# Print data of JSONObject in java.

Tags: java, json

I have a `JSONObject` consisting of a simple json document(doesn't consists nested objects or `JSONArray`). I want to print that data.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test2{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=scan.nextLine();
    JSONObject j=new JSONObject(s);
    // What code should I write here
  }
}
```

Let us say if the input is `{fname:"Stack", lname:"Overflow"}` then the output should be:-

```
fname => Stack
lname => Overflow
```

If the input is `{country:"India", city:"Delhi"}`then the output should be:-

```
country => India
city => Delhi
```

Can you please help me how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [***`documentation`***](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) you can iterate over the `keys`, and take the `values` :

1. Using `Streams` :

   ```
   j.keySet().stream().map(k -> k +"=>"+ j.get(k)).forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Using classic `for each loop`

   ```
   for(String key : j.keySet()){
       String val = j.getString(key);
       System.out.println(key +"=>"+ val);
   }
   ```

---

<sup>*Also you JSON is not valid, it should be `{"fname":"Stack", "lname":"Overflow"}`*</sup>

Comment: you should not spend this much time answering a question that has been asked and answered many times before already. Just throw a close vote at it and move on

Comment: @TimCastelijns I usually, and always do that when possible, but duplicates came after my answer, and I did not know them, also I did not use the same way but less old wy as for each and stream and not basic arry iteration like in the link

Comment: *duplicates came after my answer* - it takes 10 seconds to search for them. You can also do this yourself before answering